# How to solve Continous Error with cross_val_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am pretty new to machine learning and for the past two days, I have been trying to get rid of the `Unknown label type: 'continuous'` error.

My code: import numpy as np

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier  
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score  

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'allData.csv', sep=',')  
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:3].values  
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values  

train_features, test_features, train_lables, test_lables = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=10, random_state=10)  

feature_scaler = StandardScaler()  
train_features = feature_scaler.fit_transform(train_features)  
test_features = feature_scaler.transform(test_features)  

classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=300, random_state=10)  
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X=train_features, y=train_lables, cv="warn")  
#all_accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X=train_features, y=train_lables, cv=3)
#print(all_accuracies)
```

The error comes up at the `cross_val_score` section and I do not understand why I am getting the `Unknown label type: 'continuous'` error.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

If it would help, the data I have is all numerical has 4 columns with 300 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `RandomForestClassifier` while having a continuous output. In case the problem you are solving is regression, then you should use `RandomForestRegressor`.